# Taking the last change value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> I need to find the date when the hit = 1, and when the hit moved from
>   1 to 0.Here is the table

[image]

Once I use this code. For the following table

```
 select t1.id,t1.hit,min(datehit_1) as Hit_1, min(dateHit_0)as modelHit_0 from (
 select 
 id, 
 dateHit_0 = (case when hits = 0 then date else null end),
 datehit_1 = (case when hits = 1 then date else null end), 
 datacontrol_modelhits
 from dmt.dqm_std_model_output_history
 where id = 10 ) as t1 
 group by t1.id, t1.hit
```

> But Unfortunately, I am getting the this output:

[image]

> But I need to get this output. Want to find the last change for hit =0 which is 23/10/2019.

[image]

Comment: Try to use ORDER BY DESC at your inner SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to find the date when the hit = 1, and when the hit moved from 1 to 0.Here is the table

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(hit) over (partition by id order by coalesce(datehit_0, datehit_1) as prev_hit,
             lead(hit) over (partition by id order by coalesce(datehit_0, datehit_1) as next_hit
      from t
     ) t
where (hit = 1 and next_hit = 0) or
      (hit = 0 and prev_hit = 1);
```

If you want only the most recent two rows:

```
select top (2) t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(hit) over (partition by id order by coalesce(datehit_0, datehit_1) as prev_hit,
             lead(hit) over (partition by id order by coalesce(datehit_0, datehit_1) as next_hit
      from t
     ) t
where (hit = 1 and next_hit = 0) or
      (hit = 0 and prev_hit = 1)
order by coalesce(datehit_0, datehit_1) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have get the output. Datehit_0 = 23-10-2019, data_hits_1 = 18-10-2019, do you know how I can get output 03-10-2019 rather than 18 for datehits_1?